# basic ajax-php form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the form below. The problem with it is that after I click the submit button nothing happens. The form just disappears. Even if I insert an alert in the form function it is not shown or if delete

```
if(hasError == false){
    $(this).hide
};
```

Why is this happening?

```
<html><body><ul>
    <li><a href="#" title="Share with a friend"><span>NOTIFY A FRIEND</span></a>
        <div class="navLinks">
            <form name="send-to-friend" id="form2" action="">
                <label for="name" class="blockItem">Your Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" class="blockItem" name="your name" maxlength="60" size="30"/>
                <label for="emailFrom" class="blockItem">Your Email Address</label>
                <input type="text" id="emailFrom" class="blockItem" name="your email" maxlength="60" size="30" />
                <label for="friend-email" class="blockItem">Your friend's e-mail Address</label>
                <input  type="text" id="emailTo" class="blockItem" name="your friends email" maxlength="60" size="30"  />
                <input class="button" id="submitt2" type="submit" value="Send Message" />
                <input  class="button"  type="submit" value="Cancel"  />
            </form>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul></body></html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navLinks {
    text-align: left;
    color: #b9cce4;
    background: #2C75D8;
    padding: 0 5px;
    z-index: 10000;
        background: #333;
    }
form {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #222;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em; 
    }   
label {
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    }
.blockItem {
    display: block;
    }
.button {
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 10px;
    }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    $('.navLinks').hide();

    //hide show the main nav content
    $(".nav a").on("click", function(e) {
        $(".navLinks").hide();
        $(this).siblings(".navLinks").show();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    //error checking
    $("#submit2").click(function(){
          $(".error").hide();
          var hasError = false;
          var emailReg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

          var nameVal = $("#name").val();
          if(nameVal == '') {
            $("#name").after('<span class="error">You forgot to enter the name.</span>');
            hasError = true;
          }

          var emailToVal = $("#emailTo").val();
          if(emailToVal == '') {
            $("#emailTo").after('<span class="error">You forgot to enter the email address to send to.</span>');
            hasError = true;
          } else if(!emailReg.test(emailToVal)) {
            $("#emailTo").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid email address to send to.</span>');
            hasError = true;
          }

          var emailFromVal = $("#emailFrom").val();
          if(emailFromVal == '') {
            $("#emailFrom").after('<span class="error">You forgot to enter the email address to send from.</span>');
            hasError = true;
          } else if(!emailReg.test(emailFromVal)) {
            $("#emailFrom").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid email address to send from.</span>');
            hasError = true;
          }

          if(hasError == false){
              $(this).hide();
              $.ajax({
                    type: "POST", 
                    url: "sendemail.php", 
                    data: data,
                    success: function(){ 
                     $("#loading").fadeOut(100).hide(); $('#message-sent').fadeIn(500).show(); } 
                });
          };
          return false;
    });
```

Comment: sidenote: it should be `$(this).hide();`

Comment: Firstly remove ';' after ending this if statement of yors >> if(hasError == false)

Comment: the hide syntax is correct in the coded submitted, the : does not seem to cause problems, but I have removed it.

Comment: Just place an alert and check if you are getting inside the if condition

Comment: Are `data` initialized ?

Comment: What is your console saying, what does your network tab show in your webdeveloper tools?

Comment: I placed an alert both inside the if and inside the function and no response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems ...

Your HTML shows this (note the `id` attribute)

```
<input class="button" id="submitt2" type="submit" value="Send Message" />
```

your jQuery :

```
$("#submit2").click(function(){
```

and your listening for the `click` event on `submit2` and the `id` of the button is `submitt2`.

I would suggest that rather than listening to the `click` event of the submit button you listen for the `submit` event of the form :

```
$('#form2').submit(funciton(evt) {
   // your validation here

   // then to prevent submission
   evt.preventDefault();
}
```

Docs for the  [`.submit()` function here](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) and [`event.preventDefault()` here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

You havent initialised the data parameter

```
data: data,
```

should perhaps be

```
data: $('#form2').serialize(),
```

Read the docs on [`.serialize()` here](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: I see, however in this case should I still have an action attribute on form or not? Nvm stupid question.

Comment: How do you handle this data sent with serialize with php. Do you have the $name = $_POST['name']; or $name = $_REQUEST['name'];

Comment: also if you are yousing $('#form2').serialize(), youre input name attributes shold be correct like variables in php file

Comment: ok i have inserted the evt.preventDefault(); and it does not stop the form from submiting when the attribute is action="sendemail.php" this is very strange/

Comment: @viktor did you change the function to pass in the `evt` parameter ?

Comment: it does not work with evt, but it did work with e paramater. I also used the post() function as ajax did not worked. I will try some more and hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly your $.ajax function doing nothing, except hiding email form...

```
data: data
```

whats you are transfering here? where is writed that it's information from submited form?

also if you want to get some response data, you shold add it to your success function like

```
success: function(data){
   //show it somehow
}
```

Comment: I will change that, however, nothing happens when I delete the ajax function also.

Comment: also in yore "form" tag action="", so it's don't send information anywhere

Comment: @IgorKonopko not need for `action` attribute as the OP is specifiying the url in the `.ajax()` method

Comment: in first comment he write that it's now working even without $.ajax